# Combining d3.js with html5 drag-and-drop files

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I am trying to combine the file drag-and-drop capabilities of HTML5 with d3.js, but my lack of understanding of event handlers and variable scope are holding me back.  Right now I'm trying to import data within an event handler like so:

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .on("drop", function() {
    d3.event.stopPropagation();
    d3.event.preventDefault();

    if (d3.event.dataTransfer.files.length > 0) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function(evt) {
        docs = parseFile(evt.target.result);
        window.force = d3.layout.force()
          .nodes(docs)
          .links([])
          .size([width, height])
          .start();

        svg.selectAll("circle")
          .data(docs).enter()
          .append("circle")
          .attr("cx", function(d) {return d.x;})
          .attr("cy", function(d) {return d.y;})
          .attr("r", "8")
          .call(force.drag);
      };
      reader.readAsText(d3.event.dataTransfer.files[0]); 
    }
  });
```

First, it seems hacky to me to have to reference `svg` from inside `reader.onload` that way, but I'm not sure there's a way around it. More importantly, the force layout isn't doing anything. It prints circles to random locations after dropping the file, but they are entirely static. I'm at a loss.

---

**Update**

It seems that my problem was entirely due to lack of adding an event handler of the form `force.on("tick",update)`, where `update` resets the `x` and `y` attributes of the `text` tag. Now it works fine.

Comment: You only read the first file

Comment: True, and I changed the wording, but that doesn't really have much bearing on my problem.

Comment: Can you show the whole working example? I can't even get the "drop" event handler to fire.